# RetroPie and two Bluetooth PS3 Controllers

Tags: bluetooth, retropie

***Now working***

I have two fake PS3 controllers.  I have been able to get one working fine.  Is there anything specific to get a second one working via bluetooth?
This question by Chris Barr has some good information; [RetroPie & PS3 Controller over Bluetooth](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54522/retropie-ps3-controller-over-bluetooth?newreg=183df355f6d54079b1d0e563788a581b) .  Unfortunately, he does not clarify if he got two to work using bluetooth at the same time.

I am using the latest Retropie.  Nothing added except the controller drivers.

There is nothing special needed.  Just patience and some voodoo.

The problem apparently fixed itself.

Comment: So I just sat down to have another look at this.  Both controllers now just work.  Pushed the P3 button on them and they connected.  So far only in the Retropie menus, as it's a clean install.